# 1.16.1 Item Teleporting but how tho?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I’m asking if its possible to teleport items to a certain location because ive seen it in Bedrock Edition. But how do you do it in Java edition?

I have tried the following command:

```
/tp @e[name=coal] -120 67 890.
```

And is it possible to do it in a command block?

Answer (score 1):

Things are very different in Minecraft Java Edition. The thing that is causing your command to fail. For example, in Java Edition, we don’t test for item entities by name, instead we peek at their data and look at the item ID.

Here is a command:

```
/teleport @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:coal"}}] -120 67 890
```

And yes, command blocks will work with this command.

You can learn more about NBT, the system used to store data, on [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NBT_format) Minecraft Wiki page.